# How do I index a function call that return a array (MatLab)?

Tags: matlab

I am calling a function in matlab that returns a array but I seem to have to store it in a variable to index it.

This is what is working:

```
lol = coeffvalues(f4)
needed_ans = lol(1)
```

but coming from python I expect something like this :

```
needed_ans = coeffvalues(f4)(1)
```

without something like that I cannot pipe values as I imagine, is there a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `getfield`in matlab, this is how you can do it :

```
getfield(coeffvalues(f4),{1})
```

there are more options to get that in one lines, but I think `getfield` is the simplest. This assume that the output of your function is an array, not a cell or structure etc.

on a side note, the behavior you describe in python is reserved in matlab to access cell array elements, for example `C{4}(1)` will access the 1st element of the 4th cell structure in `C`....